# Posting with Wordpress API REST

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to automate posting entries to a blog every time a specific action happens on my website. 
I've been looking at the Wordpress documentation but I've only seen that I can put as the structure of the post. I would be interested in creating entries with text and images. Would it be possible to do this?

The text and images would be taken from the web page.

I'm using php with Laravel and the blog is in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a POST request to the "post" endpoint to POST a new post (no pun intended) ([docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post)).

Although the content parameter is said to be an object in the docs, you can pass a HTML string to it like `<h1>Some cool event happened</h1><p>See this picture</p><img src="https://some-path-to-picture.com/picture.png">`

It seems you can even add images along with your content to be hosted on your wordpress site ([see this Github question](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2563))